# PHP static code analysis tool, which detects uncaught exceptions?

Tags: php, static-code-analysis

There seems to be quite a lot of static code analysis tools for PHP, could you please suggest the one, which can detect exceptions, which are thrown in the PHP code, but are never caught? (the ones, which can theoretically stop the execution on the PHP script).

I would be happy enough to see only stuff like `throw new SomeException()`, where `SomeException` extends `Exception`.

I am not looking for something too sophisticated - just to warn me that if I run `someFunctionThatCanThrow` ('cause there is `throw` statement inside) from `index.php` (you get the point), I can get in trouble. Even if in the runtime that would never happen.

Thanks.

Comment: Impossible in the general case - not only because of `eval "$any_string()";` or `$this->$anotherstring()`.

Comment: @Piskvor, I would be happy enough to see only `throw new SomeException()`. I try not use any sort of PHP magic in my code.

Comment: Such a tool must go through every possible execution path. Thats simply too much (not only for PHP).

Comment: @KingCrunch, I would be happy enough to see some false alerts. E.g. if method a can throw an exception (there is throw statement), and it is isn't caught anywhere (for example, ran from the main()), the tool would show that, even if some conditionals were set, that would make it not possible in the runtime.

Comment: Well, the idea behind this task is qute simple - strip all code besides trowing(catching) of exeptions, classes(functions) defenitions and methods(functions) calls. A base skeleton of your project will be left. Next do a loop: run it, check for uncaught exeptions, delete 1st trow exeption(), repeat while there are some exeptions left. This looks like a few hours work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @XzKto, I'm not a fan of reinventing the wheel. In fact, I've already found exactly what I was looking for, will post my own answer.

Comment: @Fluffy, Me too, I was answering to people who said that it can't be done.

Comment: @XzKto, ok, sorry for jumping the gun)

Comment: @Fluffy, no need to be sorry, I should have been more specific :) Btw, your google skills seems to be superior to mine, so I am really looking forward to your self-answer.

Comment: @XzKto, already there. I just tried the one, which I could test online, and it did what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PHPLint](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/phplint-on-line.html) seems to be the answer. For example, it parses

```
<?php

function some()
{
    if (time() == 123) {
        throw new Exception("I can't happen");
    }
}

some();
```

, which will never throw an exception (unless you're in the past), into:

```
BEGIN parsing of test-cSdHoW
1:      <?php
2:      
3:      function some()
4:      {
5:       if (time() == 123) {
6:        throw new Exception("I can't happen");

          throw new Exception("I can't happen");
                                                \_ HERE
==== 6: notice: here generating exception(s) Exception

          throw new Exception("I can't happen");
                                                \_ HERE
==== 6: ERROR: exception(s) must be caught or declared to be thrown: Exception
7:       }
8:      }
9:      
10:     some();
==== 3: notice: guessed signature of the function `some()' as void()

        some();
             \_ HERE
==== 10: notice: here generating exception(s) Exception

        some();
             \_ HERE
==== 10: Warning: uncaught exception(s): Exception
END parsing of test-cSdHoW
==== ?: notice: unused package `dummy.php'
==== ?: notice: required module `standard'
Overall test results: 1 errors, 1 warnings.
```

So that's exactly what I was asking for :) Adding a docblock and catching the exception results in no more errors or warnings from PHPLint.

Comment: Thx, didn't know about this tool. To my TODO list.

Comment: Didn't know PHPLint can do this ^^

Answer (score 2):

As for 2015, for PhpStorm exists a SCA tool available as plugin [Php Inspections (EA Extended)](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7622?pr=phpStorm) - it does this kind of analysis, including nested calls. Plus it takes context into consideration, e.g. within __toString unhanded exceptions leading to fatals and the plugin reports this.