# How to force catching exceptions PHP

Tags: php, exception

How to force catching exceptions in PHP?

I want to force exception catching if method may return and exception and is not added to try catch block.

For example:

If an exception is not thrown developer may never know that certain kind of exception may be thrown by the method he uses. So he won't catch it. I want to make sure that every exception that can be thrown will be caught.

In case it is not, I want a fatal error, or at least an exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP static code analysis tool, which detects uncaught exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268346/php-static-code-analysis-tool-which-detects-uncaught-exceptions)

Comment: Not really, that one is not a codding practice.

Comment: Couldnt you use set_error_handler() to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: In comments it points out, that the former answer was not the actual answer to the problem. The detection of uncaught exceptions, or potentially uncaught exceptions in PHP is not supportet by the PHP parser itself. (Not like the Java compiler). You'll have to use external tools for statical code analysis to improve the quality of your code. I found this interesting answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8268875/171318

---

Original Answer:

You can register a function as global exception handler using [`set_exception_handler()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php). This function will be called by the PHP engine if an exception was not caught.

Example (from PHP manual):

```
<?php
function exception_handler($exception) {
  echo "Uncaught exception: " , $exception->getMessage(), "\n";
  exit(1);
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');

throw new Exception('Uncaught Exception');
echo "Not Executed\n";
?>
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It doesn't force developer to add exceptional situations to his code. I didn't ask how to catch uncaught exceptions, I asked how to force catching exception that is not yet even thrown

Comment: Note that this is not *incorrect*. Do you search for something like statical code analyzis? or test suite?

Comment: Something like that, i will try to edit my question to make it more clear. But I want to eliminate situation, when exception is thrown but try catch block is not added by developer. Yes of course I can catch all uncaught exceptions. But it doesn't force a developer to write a cleaner code and add exceptional situations handling to his code. If i do like you say. No one may ever know that it is possible to have an exception in certain part of the code until it is thrown and only then he will start analyzing the problem.

Comment: Yes this is something similar but doesn't suite for what I wanted. PHPLint is online analysis tool. And developer may never go there to analyze something, he just leave it as it is. What later results in serious bugs. I am thinking about adding some compilation alike mechanism to an application.

Comment: `adding some compilation alike mechanism to an application`. Happy coding! I hope it breaks nothing. What about using PHPLint as web service (or local installation) and force code check on every commit?. This would be a way you could go. Also a high unit test coverage is an indication for high quality code

Comment: Note that PHPLint is available for local usage as well http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/

Answer (score 0):

I decided to share what I do for myself considering this question.

I will add compilation mechanism to my application. So it won't be working if its not compiled first.

This will help me to force coding practices on developers and won't slow an application.

======================

Sorry, I cannot find a way to make it without slowing application. The best thing for       the moment that comes to my mind is to check file modification time when it gets included. If its not equal to compilation time then throw an exception about compilation.

But it checks date and time of all files that participated in script run after all. So if you run 1000 files in your script execution, on my pc it gets slowed for 0.022 sec. If there are around 50 files included in your script run then it is slowed by 0.0015 sec

In most cases running this kind of application will still be cheaper then fixing bugs made by developers. But it depends how fast you want your application to be.

Comment: `I will add compilation mechanism to my application` Can you explain?

Comment: Yes. I will explain when I find a good solution for it. It is a bit tricky after all.