# Easy way to list all of exceptions "try" block may produce

Tags: php, exception

Is there any easy way to find out, which types of exception I can expect in `try` block? Let's say I have:

```
<?php
try {
    foo();
} catch (\A\B\FooException $e) {

} catch (\A\B\BarException $e) {

}
```

Is there any tool which can inspect the `foo()` code for me and list all of exceptions types I can expect there? So if there is `\A\B\BazException` I forgot, I can easily add another `catch` thanks to that list. For now I use search for "Exception", but sometimes there is to many the same results.

Comment: Some IDEs can sort of do it, like PhpStorm. They can auto-create doc blocks in which all exception types of a method are listed. Not sure if this considers nested calls too, or how much more work it is to create a list of all possible exceptions a method may throw that way. But worth a look.

Comment: @deceze yes, PhpStorm can do it but as you mentioned - only for method level, it can't discover what happens underneath.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP static code analysis tool, which detects uncaught exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268346/php-static-code-analysis-tool-which-detects-uncaught-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know any tools to do that. But you can create at least the code block below:

```
catch (Exception $e) { 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO exceptions_tb ('exception_name','expection_message') VALUES ('"+$e->class+"', '"+addslashes($e->message)+"')  excetption ", $conn);
}
```

And after consult the variations of exceptions happened in all your unit tests. Or simply you can do all possible ways and input data types in your unit tests and see what exceptions will arise.
I don´t believe there is a tool that can do this for you also because the tool will need to now all possible inputs and php variables are not predefined types.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't find it more useful than searching for text occurrences containing Exception. With your solution I need to rely on perfection of unit test (which I can't) or wait for some exception actually happen which I obviously don't want to see :-) Anyway, logging the exceptions within particular `try` block is quite clever.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
catch (Exception $oError) {
    Logger::logError($oError);
}

class Logger
{    
    public static function($oError){
        // do here detection you like\want
        // you can use loops and pre-def. instances of errors

        if ($oError instanceof ExceptionCustom)
            // some actions
        }
        ...
    }

}

class ExceptionCustom extends Exception { 
    // http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php
    //...
}
```

It's only sample, base thing. You can\should do it more complicated the way you want.

**ADDED:**
Main thing that you will decide, what error and what you should do, only after you receive exception, and of course you should create default action for it (no matter what exception is thrown).

Comment: Your answer seems to be pretty much the same as the @developer3466402`s. It requires to wait for exception. I want to be prepared before it occur.

Comment: There is no way to get ALL list of exceptions can be. Why? Let's say in your team 4 members. Each do it's own exception, so php will not react on your exception but react on your team member exception. So main thing that all exceptions are extended from one single Exception class, that's why everybody do check 'after', and each member (in team) add its catch method, because no one can get all exception list, think about it. $)

Comment: There can be one solution but I think you cannot use it. In system (I mean whole code) all exceptions has to be registered somewhere. And you can get them using it (register). But I don't know such MVC\CMS, so it's just thoughts (not solution).